# Sort one array based on values of another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of pointers to objects that are instances of a class from external code that I would rather not change.

I also have a vector of ints that was generated by calling a function on each object.  So I have

```
A:  [pointerToObj1, pointerToObj2, ... pointerToObjN]
```

And

```
B:  [obj1Int, obj2Int, ..... objNInt]
```

How do I easily sort A such that it is sorted in by the values of B.  I have boost available.

That is if B were

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

I want to sort A such that it is in the order

```
[pointerToObj2, pointerToObj3, pointerToObj1]
```

In javascript you could do this like

```
B.sort(function(a,b){return A[B.indexOf(a)] < A[B.indexOf(b)];});
```

Comment: You aren't by chance doing genetic programming are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a pair vector that contains both A & B.

   ```
   vector<pair<pointerToObjType, int>> order(N);
   for (int i=0; i<N; ++i){
       order[i] = make_pair(A[i], B[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Create your custom comparator to sort the pair vector.

   ```
   struct ordering {
       bool operator ()(pair<pointerToObjType, int> const& a, 
                        pair<pointerToObjType, int> const& b) {
           return a.second < b.second;
       }
   };
   ```
3. Sort the pair vector.

   ```
   sort(order.begin(), order.end(), ordering());
   ```
4. All sorted A's can be accessed using `order[i].first`.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to store your array of "scores" in a `std::map<MyObject, int> scores` instead. Now you can create a comparator

```
bool compare(const MyObject* lhs, const MyObject* rhs) {
    return scores[*lhs] < scores[*rhs];
}
```

Now you simply do

```
std::sort(vectorOfObjects.begin(), vectorOfObjects.end(), compare);
```

Unfortunately, this requires that either `scores` is a global variable or `scores` and `compare` are packaged into the same class.

Perhaps a better approach is to use a lambda:

```
std::sort(vectorOfObjects.begin(), vectorOfObjects.end(),
    [&scores] (const MyObject* lhs, const MyObject* rhs) {scores[*lhs] < scores[*rhs];});
```

This allows you to declare `scores` as a local variable and capture it in the lambda.

One drawback to this solution is that, in order to use the `MyObject` class as a key for `std::map`, you must implement `operator<()` for the class (or a comparator to pass to the `std::map` constructor). Fortunately, you can write this as a global function and don't have to change the class itself. However, this requires comparing the objects directly in some way.

Comment: this seems like a nice clean answer, I got herohuyongtao's method working before I saw it.  Thanks

Comment: @asutherland I had an error in my original lambda implementation. I also decided to restore my original answer then show the simplified version with a lambda.

Comment: My kingdom for a zip iterator.